# How to update many mobile applications from one place?

Tags: firebase, react-native, mobile-application, auto-update, ota

I'm using React-Native. I have a mobile app and in near future I'll copy-paste it for many customers. All features will be same except colour, logo and etc. Let's assume that I have 100 mobile Apps and when there are some bugs or errors on my api or another part. I want to fix them just one time and apply it to all my mobile apps without update them on iOS-google play market. Otherwise I have to fix all my Apps separately and it will take my lot so time. I found something about it named as [EXPO-OTA(Over-to-air)](https://docs.expo.io/guides/configuring-ota-updates/) but that's not sufficient for me. That has some limit to update something. Is there any way to do it? Or Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use react-native-config for managing each app config. like color and other configurations.

Also keep the logo in android assets and link them in js code .

After that you can use react-natve-code-push to update the js bundle over the air. This way you can sync the same codebase in every app.